# Dynamic attribute in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to dynamically include/omit the disabled attribute on a button element. I have seen plenty of examples of dynamic attribute values, but not of attributes themselves. I have the following render function:

```
render: function() {
    var maybeDisabled = AppStore.cartIsEmpty() ? "disabled" : "";
    return <button {maybeDisabled}>Clear cart</button>
}
```

This throws a parse error because of the "{" character. How can I include/omit the disabled attribute based on the (boolean) result of AppStore.cartIsEmpty()?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

The cleanest way to add optional attributes (including `disabled` and others you might want to use) is currently to use [JSX spread attributes](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var opts = {};
        if (this.props.disabled) {
            opts['disabled'] = 'disabled';
        }
        return <button {...opts}>Hello {this.props.name}</button>;
    }
});

React.render((<div><Hello name="Disabled" disabled='true' />
    <Hello name="Enabled"  />
</div>)
, document.getElementById('container'));
```

By using spread attributes, you can dynamically add (or override) whatever attributes you'd like by using a javascript object instance. In my example above, the code creates a `disabled` key (with a `disabled` value in this case) when the `disabled` property is passed to the `Hello` component instance.

If you only want to use `disabled` though, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103418/95190) answer works well.

Comment: Once  in place, CSS like:
`a[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
}`
will stop actions on an element/component

Answer (score 72):

I'm using React 16 and this works for me (where `bool` is your test):

```
<fieldset {...(bool && {disabled:true})}>
```

Basically, based on the test (`bool`) you return an object with the conditional attributes or you don't.

Also, if you need to add or omit multiple attributes you can do this:

```
<fieldset {...(bool && {disabled:true, something:'123'})}>
```

For more elaborate attribute managed I suggest you prefab the object with (or without) the attributes outside of JSX.

Comment: Thanks for that simple yet very helpful answer!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 57):

You can pass a boolean to the `disabled` attribute.

```jsx
render: function() {
    return <button disabled={AppStore.cartIsEmpty()}>Clear cart</button>
}
```

```js
function Test() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={false}>Clear cart</button>
      <button disabled={true}>Clear cart</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.querySelector("#test-container"));
console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("button")));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="test-container"></div>
```

Comment: no you cannot. the presence of the disabled attribute disables the button completely. see [http://jsfiddle.net/ttjhyvmt/](http://jsfiddle.net/ttjhyvmt/)

Comment: React is clever enough to conditionally set the `disabled` attribute on the resulting HTML depending on the value you passed

http://jsfiddle.net/kb3gN/10379/

Comment: not sure how I missed that, thank you! whilst this works for my specific case, I have accepted another answer which omits/includes attributes

Comment: Had issues with IE11, however, we were not using the latest react. The JSX spread attributes answer worked.

Answer (score 6):

Far cleaner than the accepted solution is the solution which AnilRedshift mentioned, but which I'll expand on.

Simply put, HTML attributes have a name and a value.  As a shorthand, you can use the name only for "disabled", "multiple", etc.  But the longhand version still works, and allows for React to work in it's preferred way.

`disabled={disabled ? 'disabled' : undefined}` is the most legible solution.

Answer (score 6):

A simple and clean way of doing it

```
<button {...disabled && {disabled: true}}>Clear cart</button>
```

disabled should come from props like this

```
<MyComponent disabled />
```

Answer (score 5):

The version I used was:

```
<button disabled={disabled ? 'disabled' : undefined}>
    Click me (or dont)
</button>
```

Comment: It is a bad practice to use undefined in your code. It is also unnecessary as you could simply write <button disabled={disabled}> as disabled is a boolean variable than returns true or false

Comment: Why is undefined bad practice? Citation if possible. Also perhaps react properly handles bools now but at nhe time of writing your suggestion would not work correctly

Answer (score 4):

More cleaner way of doing dynamic attributes which works for any attributes is

```
function dynamicAttributes(attribute, value){
  var opts = {};
  if(typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
    opts['"'+attribute+'"'] = value;
    return opts;
  }
  return false;
};
```

Call in your react component like following

```
<ReactComponent {...dynamicAttributes("disabled",false)}
{...dynamicAttributes("data-url",dataURL)}
{...dynamicAttributes("data-modal",true)} />
```

Tips :

1. You could have `dynamicAttributes` function in a common place/utilities and
   import it to use it across all components
2. you could pass value as `null` to not render dynamic attribute

Comment: Why not do like this: <ReactComponent {...{ "data-url": dataURL }}  /> ?  it simpler and no "dynamicAttributes" needed

Comment: In case of attribute is null, we don't want react to render that attribute. example: "data-modal": null we don't want react to show data-model="null". in this case my above code wont even show attribute i.e, dynamic attribute based on value.

Answer (score 2):

You can find something similar to this at the documentation.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/transferring-props.html

In your case could be something like this

```
function MyComponent(props) {
    let { disabled, ...attrs } = props;
    if (disabled) {
        // thus, it will has the disabled attribute only if it
        // is disabled
        attrs = {
            ...attrs,
            disabled: true
        }
    };

    return (
        <button {...attrs}>MyLabel</button>
    )
}
```

This code is using ES6, but I thing you got the idea.

This is cool because you can pass many others attributes to this component and it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

In case others come here for attributes other than `disabled`, e.g., custom attributes like `data-attr`, one can assign empty string `""` as the value in the object to be spread to eliminate the value of the attribute. With the attribute name only available on the resulted HTML.

For example:

```
<div {...(trueOrFalse && { [`data-attr`]: "" })}></div>
```

Furthermore, if you wish the name of the attribute being dynamic too. Due to template strings support string interpolation, you can put state into it to make the name of attribute dynamic.

```
<div {...(trueOrFalse && { [`${state}`]: "" })}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**First you can simply check**

```
<button disabled={true}>Button 1</button>
<button disabled={false}>Button 2</button>
```

Note: **disabled value is not String, it should be *Boolean*.

**Now for dynamic. You can simply write**

```
<button type="button" disabled={disable}  
        onClick={()=>this.setSelectValue('sms')} >{this.state.sms}</button>
```

As you can see I am using disabled property and in curly brackets it can be local variable/state var. 
The variable `disable` contains values true/false.

Answer (score -3):

This could work, problem with disabled is one could not simply set boolean for it.

```
if(AppStore.cartIsEmpty()){
  return "<button disabled>Clear cart</button>"
}
else
{
  return "<button>Clear cart</button>"
}
```

Comment: I was afraid I might have to resort to this.. I'll wait to see if anybody else has any suggestions before accepting your answer