# Using pseudo-classes in React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

In my React component, I have a form with multiple input fields. In the CSS classes that I'm working with, there's an "invalid" pseudo-class that should highlight the field if its value is invalid. Currently, the input fields do not have any classes defined in my component. They're using the default styling that comes from the CSS file.

```
class MyForm extends Component {

   render() {

      return(

         // There's more code here. Not showing to keep things simple

         <input type="text" name="someProperty" value={myObject.someProperty} onChange={e => this.someFunction(e)} />

      );
   }

}
```

How do I actually use this -- meaning, how do I set the input field to invalid? I tried simply adding "invalid" to its CSS class but it didn't work.

This is what I tried with no results:

```
<input type="text" name="someProperty" className={showInvalid} value={myObject.someProperty} onChange={e => this.someFunction(e)} />
```

UPDATE:

Doing a bit more research on pseudo-classes, they do NOT go into the class. So in HTML, the input field would simply appear as below:

```
<input name"someProperty" invalid />
```

Comment: className should be a string. I think it probably thinks className is undefined since showInvalid is undefined.

Comment: See my update. Looks like it should not go into the className.

Comment: Ah some reason I brain farted... Didn't see the psuedo. My bad

Comment: It looks like you can't use pseudo classes in inline style. Which is basically what you are doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269669/css-pseudo-elements-in-react.

Never had that come up

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm coming to that conclusion as well! Bummer!

Comment: look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187781/react-js-disable-button-when-input-is-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the `pattern` attribute on the `input` elements.

> [**When an element is invalid**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation#When_an_element_is_invalid)
>
> *The element matches the :invalid CSS pseudo-class; this will let you apply a specific style to invalid elements. Similarly, valid elements match the :valid pseudo-class....*
>
> *...All `<input>`  elements can be validated using the pattern attribute. This attribute expects a case sensitive Regular Expression as its value...*

```js
var NumberInput = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?" step="0.01" title="This should be a number with up to 2 decimal places." placeholder="Price" />;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberInput />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: #ff3333;
}

input:valid {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea! I'll give it a try and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, no problem.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work but it should. We simply put a regex into pattern, right? For example if I want to make sure it's a number with two decimal points, I should be able to use pattern="/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$/", correct?

Comment: I've made an update to the fiddle using an `input` with `type` set to `number`, allowing up to two decimal places.

Comment: Sorry, my first pattern was wrong, this should work `[0-9]+([\,|\.][0-9]+)?`. Check out the code snippet.

Comment: This is working nicely. My CSS file was cached so the invalid pseudo-class that I had added wasn't coming through. I think this is a nice and clean approach because it's all CSS based.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, that is what you're looking for

```
className={`${this.state.showInvalid} ? 'invalidCssClassName' : 'nonInvalidCssClassName'`}
```

That means you should store somewhere (state or props) the value which will be responsible for evaluating the class name. In that case when `showInvalid` is evaluated to true, CSS class will be `invalidCssClassName` otherwise `nonInvalidCssClassName`

Comment: See my update. Research shows me that pseudo-classes are not used in class names.