# Disable/Enable submit button in React JS USING FUNCTION

Tags: reactjs

I want to disable/enable a form submit button using a function.
Here is my code to explain what I want:

```
isDisabled = () => {
    //logic to define if button should be disabled or not
    //return boolean true or false based on that
}


render() {
    return (
        <form className="forgot-password-form">
            //form fields
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={this.isDisabled} />
        </form>
    );
}
```

This is just to show an idea what I want to do :) Of course `render()` will be in component and all.

Currently it gives me warning:

> Warning: Invalid value for prop `disabled` on  tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: are you using onSubmit? if so you can just have a helper that returns the code you want to execute if not disabled and if disabled it just runs a function that returns false

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/n95yyov50

Comment: onSubmit will run when you click on submit, I don't want to let a user click on submit button if form is not having certain conditions fulfilled. Kind of same like invalid functionality in angular which comes out of the box.

Comment: @ RIYAJ KHAN I dont understand how that answers my question :) You are disabling it always and making a function call onClick :D

Comment: If you can disable when the inputs of the form are empty, you can check by the state, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187781/react-js-disable-button-when-input-is-empty)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're passing a function to the `disabled` prop, you have to execute this function to pass the boolean result of this function instead :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={this.isDisabled()}
```

Comment: I am not at system right now but I guess it will work. So  +1 and accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.13.3/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@0.13.3/dist/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx;harmony=true">void function() { "use strict";

var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {}
  },
  isDisabled(){
    return true;   // for disable button return true otherwise false
   // return false;
  },
  render() {
    return <div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={this.isDisabled()}/>
    
    </div>
  }
})

React.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))

}()</script>
```

Comment: Thank you but I have already accepted Dyo answer which was same. However thanks for yours too. +1.