# Disable submit button until the user write number

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I have a quick question, I am trying to build an exchange react app that converts currency.
I want to make by submit button disabled until the user type number in the desired input, I see a lot of answers but all of them using Jquery, have any solutions for only JS?
my HTML code :

```html
       <div id='mainHomeDiv'>
            <h1>Exchange</h1>
            <lable>From :</lable> 
            <select>
                <option value=''>type</option>
                <option value='Dollar'>Dollar</option>
                <option value='Euro'>Euro</option>
                <option value='NIS'>NIS</option>
            </select> <input type='number' id='amountInput' placeholder='Amount'></input> <br /> <br />
            <label>To :</label>
            <select>
                <option value=''>type</option>
                <option value='Dollar'>Dollar</option>
                <option value='Euro'>Euro</option>
                <option value='NIS'>NIS</option>
            </select> <br /> <br />
            <button disabled="disabled">START</button> <br /> <br />
            <button>Update</button> <button>Share on facebook</button> <button>View your exchange list</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: jQuery is "just JavaScript", you've also tagged this ReactJS. If you're using React then the answer becomes *dramatically* different.

Comment: You should [learn how to use the label element properly](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/). Without a for attribute or a form control inside it, a label is useless. You also need to spell label correctly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187781/how-to-disable-a-button-when-an-input-is-empty

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps u

i have added an event `onkeyup` to your textbox code to run the function,

```js
var enbbtn = document.getElementById("tgbtn");
var txtchng = document.getElementById("amountInput");
function enabledbtn() {
if (txtchng.value.length > 0) {
enbbtn.disabled = false;
} else {
enbbtn.disabled = true;
}
}
```

```html
<div id='mainHomeDiv'>
            <h1>Exchange</h1>
            <lable>From :</lable> 
            <select>
                <option value=''>type</option>
                <option value='Dollar'>Dollar</option>
                <option value='Euro'>Euro</option>
                <option value='NIS'>NIS</option>
            </select> <input type='number' id='amountInput' placeholder='Amount' onkeyup="enabledbtn()"></input> <br /> <br />
            <label>To :</label>
            <select>
                <option value=''>type</option>
                <option value='Dollar'>Dollar</option>
                <option value='Euro'>Euro</option>
                <option value='NIS'>NIS</option>
            </select> <br /> <br />
            <button id="tgbtn" disabled="true">START</button> <br /> <br />
            <button>Update</button> <button>Share on facebook</button> <button>View your exchange list</button>
        </div>
```