# How to enable/disable button on selecting radio button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-bootstrap, redux-form

I am new to reactjs. Currently in my application, I want to enable and disable the button on selecting radio button. Below is my code :

```
class Radiosample extends React.Component {

   render() {
      <table>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>
              <Field name="radio1" component="input" id="radio1" type="radio"/> // On check of this radio button below button should enable.. 
           </td>
           <Button name="button" id="btn">Click Me</Button>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
   }
}

export default Radiosample
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic attribute in ReactJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103096/dynamic-attribute-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 3):

You should use **state**, otherwise the page would not be rerendered.

So *onClick* or *onChange* event you need to update **state**

```
setButtonDisability = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => this.setState({ isButtonDisabled: /* value from event target */ })
```

Just add to your `<Field />` component `onClick={this.setButtonDisability}` or `onChange={this.setButtonDisability}`.

And then use it in render function

```
<Button name="button" disabled={this.state.isButtonDisabled} />
```

You should definitly go through an [oficial intro tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not very generic, but shouldn't this simple thing work?

```
class Radiosample extends React.Component {
    function disableButton() {
        document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;
    } 

    render() {
      <table>
       <tbody>
         <tr>
           <td>
              <Field name="radio1" onclick="this.disableButton()" component="input" id="radio1" type="radio"/> // On check of this radio button below button should enable.. 
           </td>
           <Button name="button" id="btn">Click Me</Button>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
   }
}

export default Radiosample
```