# React - Pass prop without a value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native-base

I am using **NativeBase** with **React Native**.

NativeBase buttons created this way:

```
    <Button warning>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
    </Button>
```

Instead of **warning** you can use different types, such as **info** or **success**.

Now, I want to create those buttons based on a prop and trying to do something like this:

```
<Button {this.props.type}>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</Button>
```

But I cannot find a way to do it because this prop does not have a value.

Is it possible to pass props without a value?

Comment: `<Button {...this.props}>` could help you if you can destructure the props object, even if props is empty object it works out fine

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29103727/479167) might be helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Component props that can be passed without value are basically `boolean` props and are resolved as `true`.

These two are equal:

```
<Button primary />
<Button primary={true} />
```

Considering above, you can make use of [spread attribute](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) syntax:

```
<Button {...{ [this.props.type]: true }}>
    <Text>Hello</Text>
</Button>
```

**EDIT** (detailed explanation):

Let's say your `this.props.type` is "success", `Button` element would resolve to this (because of usage of dynamic property name):

```
<Button {...{ success: true }}>
```

Now when you destruct object (these three dots), you'll get all of its properties and corresponding values as element's props:

```
<Button success={true} >
```

As I've already mentioned, please take a look at [this explanation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes).

Comment: Thank you, it works. Could you please explain why it works? I am not sure I fully understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to pass props without a value.
If you do this then a boolean value true will be passed. Otherwise if you want to pass false as a boolean value then mention explicitly like warning={false}.