# Unexpected token, expected "..." React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I want to put "defaultChecked" attribute to JSX input element but the compiler requires me to use spread operator for **activeModal** state? Why is that? The state is either true or false:

`<input  name="radio-size"value="small" type="radio" id="small" {**activeModal**?"checked":""} className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"></input>`

Comment: Try this `<input checked={activeModal}></input>`

Comment: ^ assuming `activeModal` is a boolean

Comment: See also: [Dynamic attribute in ReactJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103096/dynamic-attribute-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSX expects, that if you put an an expression inside `{}` somewhere that it expects a prop name, then that expression will be `...someObject` where `someObject` contains a props to values mapping.

e.g.

```
const myObject = {
    name: "radio-size",
    value: "small",
    // etc
}

<input {...myObject} />
```

It doesn't expect a string of JSX to insert.

If you want to set a boolean prop, then just assign boolean to the prop:

```
<input checked={activeModal} (your other props) />
```

Comment: What if I want to put a comment in that context?

Comment: @Joymaker — Stackoverflow has [a feature for asking new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Link back to this answer (see the *Share* link above) if it will help provide context. Read [ask] and make an attempt before you actually ask the question though. Don't forget to include a [mcve].