# Ternary operator on a element attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I don't know if this is possible, but I wanted to check for a `window.OneTrust` object and if it doesn't exist, to keep the attribute as `src`, otherwise keep it as `data-src` and change the type.

Here is what I'm talking about:

If `window.OneTrust` exists, keep it as:

```
<script
  type='text/plain'
  id='google-maps-api-script'
  className='optanon-category-C0004'
  data-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"
></script>;
```

Otherwise, have it as:

```
<script
  type='text/javascript'
  id='google-maps-api-script'
  className='optanon-category-C0004'
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"
></script>;
```

Is there a way that I can have a ternary operator for type/src instead of doing it like this?

```
if (!window.OneTrust) {
  <script
    type='text/javascript'
    id='google-maps-api-script'
    className='optanon-category-C0004'
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"
  ></script>;
} else {
  <script
    type='text/plain'
    id='google-maps-api-script'
    className='optanon-category-C0004'
    data-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"
  ></script>;
}
```

Comment: you either have to document.write or createElement/appendChild

Comment: Are you just trying to create a dynamic attribute? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103096/dynamic-attribute-in-reactjs

Comment: Please update your question to explain whether you are using JSX. What you have is invalid syntax for JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.write` in a `<script>` element.

```
<script>
if (!window.OneTrust) {
  document.write(`<script
    type='text/javascript'
    id='google-maps-api-script'
    class='optanon-category-C0004'
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"
  ><\/script>`);
} else {
  document.write(`<script
    type='text/plain'
    id='google-maps-api-script'
    class='optanon-category-C0004'
    data-src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<?php echo get_field('google_maps_api_key', 'option') ?>&v=weekly"
  ><\/script>`);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not raw HTML??? it's JSX. I'm judging by the `className` attribute.

Comment: @JuanMendes, someone edited my question into `className`, it was HTML `class=` before.

Comment: Don't you need to escape the closing script tag? [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)